# Bitwise OR mask yields unexpected negative number

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I am experimenting with the bitwise operators in javascript in an attempt to gain intuition. I want to input two 32 bit binary literals, OR them together, and output the result in a binary format. Taking the case of a 4-bit analog to my code below, I would expect that ORing together 0b1000 and 0b0100 would yield 1100. And indeed it does! However, when I run the program below I get -1000000000000000000000000000000. I know enough about javascript to suspect that the problem may have to do with the fact that the language treats its 64-bit double precision floating point numbers as 32-bit chunks (if I can call them that?) I can't however easily connect that underlying reality to the curious behavior of the code below. Any thoughts?

```js
let initial = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;
let orMask = 0b01000000000000000000000000000000;
console.log(initial.toString(2));
console.log(orMask.toString(2));
console.log((initial | orMask).toString(2));
```

Comment: `initial` has bit 31 set ... i.e. it's a negative signed 32bit value ... when you log it the first time, it's just 2^32 .. but bitwise ops work like signed 32bit numbers

Comment: Does JavaScript support unsigned numbers? It's likely being interpreted as a signed 32-bit.

Comment: `|` operates on signed 32-bit integers. (Most of the bitwise operators do, except `>>>`, which is unsigned 32-bit – take a look at `((initial | orMask) >>> 0).toString(2)`.)

Comment: The first number is minus sign when it ORed by the second one caused becoming negative by that (Just makes that negative)